# Prove that a function is not globally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Here is the function : $f(t,x)=e^{tx}$ on $\mathbb{R\times R}$.

First the function is $\mathcal{C^1}$ so it's locally Lipschtiz in $x$ on $\mathbb{R\times R}$. Then I try to prove if it's globally Lipschitz in $x$ on $\mathbb{R\times R}$.

I want to use the argument of uniform continuity with sequences. So here I pick $x_n = n$ and $y_n= n +\frac{1}{n}$ and let $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

So I got : $\vert x_n -y_n\vert \le \frac{1}{n}$ and $\vert f(t,x_n)-f(t,y_n)\vert =\vert e^{tn}\vert \vert 1- e^{\frac{t}{n}}\vert$ which is equivalent for $n\to \infty$ to $\vert \frac{te^{tn}}{n} \vert \to +\infty$ if $t\ne 0$.

So $\vert f(t,x_n)-f(t,y_n)\vert > \varepsilon$

If $t=0$ then $\vert f(t,x_n)-f(t,y_n)\vert =0$ indeed $\vert e^{tn}\vert \vert 1- e^{\frac{t}{n}}\vert \to 0$

That means that there is no uniform continuity for $f$ on $\mathbb{R-\{0\}\times R}$. So it's not globally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R-\{0\}\times R}$.

I don't know if it's the right method to answer because I was wondering if I used correctly the parameter $t$. What can I say for $t=0$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312695/locally-or-globally-lipschitz-functions) may help.

Comment: @Mattos He did not use the uniform continuity argument

Answer (score 0):

Your argument, in particular the sentence containing "equivalent", does not seem stringent to me.

It is true that proving the function is not uniformly continuous in $x$ for given $t$ settles the claim. But in this simple example theres is no gain: We would then have to argue with $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s, whereas the Lipschitz property is in terms of simple inequalities about $f$.

When $t=0$ then $\phi(x):=f(0,x)\equiv1$; whence $f$ is globally Lipschitz in $x$ for this value of $t$.

Let a $t>0$ be given (the case $t<0$ is similar). Assume $x<y$. Then by the mean value theorem there is a $\xi\in\ ]x,y[\ $ with
$$e^y-e^x=t e^{t\xi}(y-x)\geq t e^{tx}(y-x)\ .$$
It follows that
$${f(t,y)-f(t,x)\over y-x}\geq t e^{tx}\ ,$$
and here the right hand side is unbounded when $x\to\infty$. This implies that there is no constant $L_t$ such that
$$|f(t,y)-f(t,x)|\leq L_t\>| y-x|$$
for all $x$, $y\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Ok, first thanks for answering. I think it's "${f(t,y)-f(t,x)\over y-x}\leq t e^{tx}$" when you used the mean value theorem and I confirm that it's the most efficient method. Also with the argument of uniform continuity, I took $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ that means that I can pick two sequences which are very close. Then, when I compose by $f$ the distance becomes strictly bigger than $\varepsilon$ for $n\to \infty$. So I do not see why we cannot solve the problem with this argument.
Finally I used the word "equivalent" to determine the limit of the expression.